# Zend Form in Modal - Submit Form

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework, submit, zend-form

I have a question about using a zend form in a twitter bootstrap modal. This is what I have:

In my Controller:

```
public function accountAction() {

    $form = new Form_CancelAccount();
    $this->view->form = $form;

    // Some executions and view params for the view, ex:
    /*if ($user->getRecurlyId() && NameSpace_Feature_Access_RoleHelper::hasAccess('show_billing')) {
        try {
            $account = Recurly_Account::get($user->getRecurlyId());
            $this->view->token = $account->hosted_login_token;
            $this->view->show_billing = true;
        } catch (Recurly_NotFoundError $e) {
            $this->view->show_billing = false;
        }
    } else {
        $this->view->show_billing = false;
    }*/

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($_POST)) {

        $data = $form->getValues();
        var_dump($data);

    } else {
        var_dump("it didn't work!");
    }
}
```

My CancelAccount Form:

```
<?php

class Form_CancelAccount extends NameSpace_Form_Base
{
  public function __construct($options = null) {

    parent::__construct($options);

    $this->setName('cancelaccount');

    $element = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('reason');
    $element->addMultiOptions(array(
        'It is really bad!' => 'bad',
        'No time for it!' => 'notime',
        'Other option:' => 'otheroption'
    ))->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'user/radio.phtml'))));

    $this->addElement($element);

    $this->addElement('text', 'otheroption', array(
        'attribs' => array(
            'class' => 'input-block-level otheroption',
            'size'  => 30,
            'placeholder' => 'Other option'
        ),
        'decorators' => $this->elementDecoratorsNoTag
    ));
  }
}
```

In my View:

```
// Some data sent from the controller
<h4>Delete account</h4>
<p>Deleting of your account implies your account and the related data will be deleted. Please note that this is not reversible.</p>

<button type="button" data-target="#cancelModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary">Delete account</button>
<div class="modal hide fade" id="cancelModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php echo $this->form; ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="OK" form="cancelaccount">
    <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-default close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

But I always get the output `'it didn't work!'` from the var_dump when the form isn't valid ... . What's the best way to do this? And how does it comes it's always not valid?

**UPDATE:**
When I leave out the `"&& $form->isValid($_POST)"` in my if statement I come in the statement, but my var_dump shows this:

> array (size=2)
>       'reason' => null
>       'otheroption' => null

My response:
[image]

The problem is that my radiobuttons aren't valid ... How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the form is using a `POST` method?

Comment: Yes, when I leave the "&& $form->isValid($_POST)" out of my if I get a response. Only the fields are empty .. (updated begin post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem where my radiobuttons. Change the radiobuttons in my form to:

```
$this->addElement('radio', 'reason', array(
        'label'=>'Reason:',
        'multiOptions'=>array(
            'bad' => 'It is really bad!',
            'notime' => 'No time for it!',
            'otheroption' => 'Other option:'
        ),
    ));
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($_POST)) {

    $data = $form->getValues();
    var_dump($data);

} else {
    var_dump("it didn't work!");
}
```

to

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()){
    $data = $form->getValues();
    var_dump($data);

    } else {
        var_dump("it didn't work!");
    }
}
```

and remember put this to last line of action:

```
$this->view->form = $form;
```

*i'm sorry, i speak English not well.*

[image]

Comment: The problem is that my radiobuttons aren't valid, how can I fix this.

Comment: I have tested your code, its working, i saw POST data is right in debug environment (firebug) and radio value is there.
Just see Image in my post.

You may need to make some validations to form input.